# Android: app crashes after downloading JS bundle

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

When i run my app on the ios simulator, it works without crashing. But when i run it on the android simulator, expo downloads JS bundle but after 2-3 seconds (on the expo loading), it crashes, returning me on the android home...

App.js :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'Center',
        alignItems: 'Center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: 'rgb(44,44,44)',
          textAlign: 'center',
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        Hello World!
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lowercase value of strings in style.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center', // <-- fixed
        alignItems: 'center', // <-- fixed
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          color: 'rgb(44,44,44)',
          textAlign: 'center',
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        Hello World!
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```